# ¿Cómo paralelizar un for en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

Estoy trabajando con threads en python. 
Mi pregunta es si se puede que a un ciclo *for in range(10)* tenga 2 hilos, donde el hilo1 ejecute el for desde el 0 al 4 y el hilo2 haga el for desde el 5 al 10 y se hagan paralelamente. 
Estoy haciendo como el código de abajo, pero lo hace en solo un hilo al parecer
Gracias de antemano

```
def forhilos1():
    for i in range(5):
        print(i,'Hilo:', 
              threading.current_thread().getName())


def forhilos2():
    for i in range(5,10):
       print(i,'Hilo:', 
              threading.current_thread().getName())


hilo = threading.Thread(target=forhilos1())

hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=forhilos2())

hilo.start()    
hilo2.start()
```

Y me ejecuta esto: 
0 Hilo: MainThread
1 Hilo: MainThread
2 Hilo: MainThread
3 Hilo: MainThread
4 Hilo: MainThread
5 Hilo: MainThread
6 Hilo: MainThread
7 Hilo: MainThread
8 Hilo: MainThread
9 Hilo: MainThread

Comment: Hola Paule, **a `target` se le pasa una referencia al callable de turno**,tu le estás pasando el retorno de la función,no una referencia a ella. En vez de, `threading.Thread(target=forhilos1())` debe ser `threading.Thread(target=forhilos1)`,se te han colado los paréntesis. Con eso le estás pasando a cada hilo el retorno de las funciones (`None`)... Posiblemente veas que se ejecutan en orden a pesar de todo, esto se debe a que realmente el tiempo de ejecución de cada hilo es mínima y no se cambia de hilo, si añades un delay en el `for` (con `time.sleep` por ejemplo) si verás como salta de hilo.

Comment: @FJSevilla Deberías convertir tu comentario en una respuesta, y si haces una explicación sobre pasar la *referencia* a pasar la *instancia* ya te coronas. Un saludo.